# complex analysis bound the integral |I|

Tags: complex-analysis

I have started doing my homework and I need to advice how to continue in my calculation. Can you give me a hint please? Thank you very much. :) I have everything described.

$\int_L(1-2Im(z)) dz$, where L is the lower half of the circle $|z-1| = 1$.

About me, due to L is the half of the circle, $z$ will be:

$z(t) = z_0 + R e^{it}   $, in my example is $R = Z_0 = 1$.

So $z(t) = 1 + e^{it} = 1 + cos(t) + i*sin(t)$, so $Im z = sin(t)$.

I will create the integra: $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}(1-2sin(t))i*e^{it} dt$. :) What do you think? I am not sure about boundaries in integral - pi and 2* pi, but if I want to have L as lower half of circle,.. I think thai it could be.

$dz$ in integral is $i * e^{it} dt$, because $-sin(t)dt + i*cos(t)dt = i * (cos(t) + i* sin(t)) dt$.

And now I am really not sure about integration, please, could you check it, if it is corrct?

$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} i e ^{t} - 2sin(t)ie^{it} dt = \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} icos(t) - sin(t) -2sin(t)*(icos(t) - sin(t)) = \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} icos(t) - sin(t) - 2cos(t)sin(t)*i + 2sin^2(t) dt = [isin(t) + cos(t) + \frac{1}{2}cos(2t)*i + t - \frac{1}{2}sin(2t)]_{\pi}^{2\pi} = 1 +
 \frac{1}{2}i
+ 2 \pi - (-1 + \frac{1}{2}i + \pi) = 2 + \pi.$

It is all. Do you think that my result is correct? It is my firs time which I do integrals in complex numbers, so I am not really sure and will be grateful for your comments. :) Thanks.

Please ignore photos under this text I have everything rewrited.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use Markdown + MathJax to express your work. Reading handwriting takes much longer

Comment: Can I ask what is Markdown + MathJax. I wrote this text really carefully and a long time, I think that it is is easy to read it.

Comment: The problem is that there is so much to read here (and there a few sentences I can't read at all... I am not particularly good at reading handwriting). Mathjax is an online, attempted implementation of LaTeX in the browser this site uses for rendering math... for example, putting \sin x between dollars signs shows $\sin x$.

Comment: I would recommend attempting to write up your post in text form as clearly as you can, and to write down only the details that are absolutely necessary.

Comment: I will rewrite it :) The mistake is friend :)

Comment: I have checked the work you wrote, and it seems to all be correct. Well done! @lida

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :)